# Git pull failed, get "The remote end hung up unexpectedly", Windows XP Jenkins slave

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a legacy project has to be built on a windows XP machine, so we set it up as a Jenkins slave. We believe we've set up environment properly, because we can successfully run "Git Pull" in both Git Bash and Dos command window on that XP machine. However, when try to run build job from Jenkins, it always failed at Git Pull commnand.

We've tried run Git Pull in two different ways: (for security purpose, I covered some path or server name with `XXXXX`)

1/ Run "Git Pull" in dos batch file, when that batch is called, we get error message in build console output like:

```
C:\sXXXXXX\cXXXXXX\gXXXXX>git checkout . 

C:\sXXXXXX\cXXXXXX\gXXXXX>git pull -v ssh://oXXXXXX@sXXXXX/git/cXXXXX/gXXXXX.git 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

2/ Using Git plug-in in Jenkins, we get error message like:

```
Building remotely on buildbox1 in workspace C:\sXXXXX\cXXXX\gXXXXX
Checkout:gXXXXX / C:\sXXXXX\cXXXX\gXXXXX - hudson.remoting.Channel@62452c45:buildbox1
Using strategy: Default
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://oXXXXXX@sXXXXX/git/cXXXXX/gXXXXX.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" fetch -t     ssh://oXXXXXX@sXXXXXX/git/cXXXXX/gXXXXX.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status     code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:863)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:824)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:198)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:1071)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$100(GitSCM.java:76)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1076)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1044)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2273)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1083)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1044)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2273)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone can help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Jenkins slave agent does have a `HOME` environment variable setup (make a simple job which would just `echo %HOME%`): it needs it to find your public and private keys.

Comment: We did set HOME environment variable, it's pointing to the C:\Documents and Settings\<Login User>, and there's .ssh sub folder, all the private key and pub keys are in that sub folder